# Prove that, every solution of the scalar system: $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y,\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{2y}{t},(t \ge 1) $ is bounded in domain $[1, +\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, systems-of-equations

**EDITED**

I have a problem:

Prove that, every solution of the scalar system:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y,\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{2y}{t},(t \ge 1) $$ *is bounded* in domain $[1, +\infty)$, but this system's **not uniformly stable** in domain $1 \le t, t_0 < +\infty$.

I have thought about my problem. But I still have no solution.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What did you get as solutions to $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: Can you write it as $dy/(2y) = -(dt/t)$ and integrate, simplify? You should get $y(t) = c_1/t^2$, and $x(t) = c_2-c_1/t$. Regards

Comment: $\frac{dy}{2y}=-\frac{dt}{t} \implies \int \frac{dy}{2y}=-\int \frac{dt}{t} \implies \ln y=\ln\frac{1}{t^2}+\ln C_1 \implies y=\frac{C_1}{t^2}$, and $  x=-\frac{C_1}{t}+C_2$.    Is that Ok! **Amzoti**

Comment: I have edited! (this is a typo by $\LaTeX$). I'm sorry Amzoti!

Comment: Definition 4.2, just show it for each solution. http://www.mathdb.org/notes_download/elementary/algebra/ae_A1.pdf. As another hint, can you plot for functions and see if they are within a band $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: Since your hint, i showed that x,y are bounded. But what about completely unstable, unstable? Amzoti?

Comment: I mean $\exists \epsilon >0, t_0>1$ such that $\forall \delta >0, \exists x_\delta(t): \left \| x_\delta(t) \right \| \ge \epsilon $

Comment: `(stable-homotopy-theory)`? What the...

Comment: I'm sorry. I removed tag.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

We can solve this system and obtain:

- $x(t) = -\dfrac{c_1}{t} + c_2$
- $y(t) = \dfrac{c_1}{t^2}$
- We can verify that these do indeed solve the system.
- We now have to show that these solutions are bounded or unbounded (use the definition and find the lower and upper bound of each over the defined range).

What conclusions can we draw about the stability of the system?

Comment: @kimtahe6: I added the hints as an answer as I hate leaving open questions. This system is stable! If we had chosen $t \in [0, + \infty)$, then we got a problem! Regards

Comment: @kimtahe6: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: Needs another TU! +1

Comment: Hihi :), sorry **Amzoti**! Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, this system is stable. I agree with you, since $x(t),y(t)$ are bounded.

Comment: That's so true...I tell you, although I'll have more time to "play with" again, I don't want to spend much more time than I have been on MSE. The dynamics here can be very counterproductive and alienating to many of us!

Answer (score 0):

$1/$ We'll show that $x,y$ are bounded in $\left [1, \infty  \right )$;

- Since $$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{2y}{t} \implies \dfrac{dy}{y}=-2\dfrac{dt}{t}\implies \int\dfrac{dy}{y}=\int-2\dfrac{dt}{t}\implies \ln|y|=\ln\frac{1}{t^2}+\ln|c_1|$$ Therefore $y=\dfrac{c_1}{t^2}$.
- Since $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y\implies x=\int\dfrac{c_1\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}=-\dfrac{c_1}{t}+c_2, \forall c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus, we have $$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } x= -\dfrac{c_1}{t}+c_2\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } y= \dfrac{c_1}{t^2}.
\end{cases}$$

$|x(t)|=\left |-\dfrac{c_1}{t}+c_2  \right |\le \left |\dfrac{c_1}{t}  \right |+\left | c_2 \right | \overset{t\ge 1}{\rightarrow} |x(t)|\le |c_1|+|c_2|$. 
And $|y(t)|=\left | \dfrac{c_1}{t^2} \right |\le \left |  c_1\right |, \forall t\ge 1$.

$2/$ This system is **not uniformly stable**:

- We'll find $X(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of the scalar system:

We have $(x(t),y(t))=(-\dfrac{c_1}{t}+c_2;\dfrac{c_1}{t^2})=c_1(-\dfrac{1}{t},\dfrac{1}{t^2})+c_2(1,0)=c_1u+c_2v$.

Thus, $u,v$ are solutions of the scalar system (with $c_1=1,c_2=0$ and $c_1=0,c_2=1$).

Moreover, if $\alpha u+\beta v=0$ then

$$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } -\dfrac{\alpha}{t}+\beta= 0\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } -\dfrac{\alpha}{t^2}=0.
\end{cases}$$
$\implies \alpha=\beta=0$. So the system $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent.

Hence, $$X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
 & -\dfrac{1}{t}& 1\\ 
 & \dfrac{1}{t^2}& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is the fundamental matrix of the scalar system.

It means the Cauchy matrix: $K(t,s)=X(t)X^{-1}(s)$ is not bounded.

- We have $$K(t,s)=\begin{pmatrix}
   & -\dfrac{1}{t}& 1\\ 
   & \dfrac{1}{t^2}& 0
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
   & 0& s^2\\ 
   & 1& s
  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
   & 1& -\dfrac{s^2}{t}+s\\ 
   & 0& \dfrac{s^2}{t^2}
  \end{pmatrix}$$
- Now, we assume that $K(t,s)$ is bounded, then $\exists M>0$ such that:
  $$\|K(t,s)\| \le M, \forall t \ge s \ge 1$$
  Taking $t=s^2\ge s\ge 1 \implies -\dfrac{s^2}{t}+s=-1+s \to +\infty$, when $s \to \infty (\text{conflict}). \blacksquare $.
  **QED**.